# Python - "Converting Nested Json to CSV Function" can't find its attribute for Converting Nested Json

Tags: python, function

I am trying to create a function called "JsonTransformer" on Jupyter notebookin order to convert JSON data to csv format. I firstly saved it on Jupyter Notebook and tried to import it and run it for testing with a json file.

Below the codes which I used and the whole code works without any problem and could get csv files. However, whenever I try to import the created function on a new Jupyter notebook; my function can't find its "`Json_to_dataframe`" attribute.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from copy import deepcopy

class JsonCsvConverter:

   def cross_join(self, left, right):
       new_rows = [] if right else left
       for left_row in left:
           for right_row in right:
            temp_row = deepcopy(left_row)
            for key, value in right_row.items():
                temp_rem, list):
            yield from flatten_list(elem)
        else:
            yield elem

    def flatten_list(self, data):
        for elem in data:
            if isinstance(elem, list):
                yield from flatten_list(elem)
           else:
               yield elem


   def json_to_dataframe(data_in):
       def flatten_json(data, prev_heading=''):
           if isinstance(data, dict):
               rows = [{}]
               for key, value in data.items():
                   rows = cross_join(rows, flatten_json(value, prev_heading + '.' + key))
           elif isinstance(data, list):
               rows = []
               for i in range(len(data)):
                   [rows.append(elem) for elem in flatten_list(flatten_json(data[i], prev_heading))]
           else:
            rows = [{prev_heading[1:]: data}]
        return rows

    return pd.DataFrame(flatten_json(data_in))



import JsonTransformer
if __name__ == '__main__':
        with open('cnntv_json') as json_file:
            json_data = json.load(json_file)

    df = JsonTransformer.json_to_dataframe(json_data)
    df.to_csv('cnntv.csv', mode='w')
```

However; I always get the error: `"Module JsonTransformer" has no attribute 'json_to_dataframe'` when I try to import the function on a new Jupyter notebook page; it seems that it can't see its attribute.

How can I solve this problem? Would be glad if someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: The code which declares a class does not expose this method name. Perhaps you meant for this method to be outside the `class` block? Or perhaps you meant for it to be a `@staticmethod` within the class (in which case you have to call it through the class, like `JsonTransformer.json_to_dataframe(...)`)